# PL/SQL Adding hours to timestamp parameter

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got parameter

```
:dateFrom
```

which gonna be used as an argument in a function as a TIMESTAMP. I need to add to :dateFrom + 7 hours, how can I do that?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, to help you out in the future please reference [ask]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your parameter is not already a timestamp, use to_timestamp or to_date to convert it:

```
to_timestamp(dateFrom,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

(substitute the appropriate mask based on the format of your input parameter)

Then just add 7/24.

```
to_timestamp(dateFrom,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + 7/24;
```

Adding 1 adds a full day, so adding 1/24 adds 1 hour.

This can also be done with the INTERVAL operator:

```
to_timestamp(dateFrom,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '7' hour
```

Comment: What data type is :dateFrom?

Comment: I updated to include a conversion to timestamp in case your input parameter is coming in as a varchar (you didn't specify).

Comment: to_timestamp(dateFrom,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '7' hour THIS help me so much, cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some PL/SQL that will:

```
DECLARE
  dateFrom TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  dateFrom := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BEFORE :: ' || dateFrom);
  dateFrom := dateFrom + INTERVAL '2' HOUR;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AFTER :: ' || dateFrom);
END;
/
```

Look into the [`INTERVAL`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Interval) operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

select  dateFrom  + interval '7' hours from dual

Answer (score 0):

In the arithmetic of the dates, in Oracle, when you add a number, it is intended as NUMBER OF DAYS.

7 hours are 7/24 days, so you have simply to add 7/24.